# Search a file directory that is given as an input?

Tags: python

So i've been given a task to take 3 parameters from a user, and then do these tasks:

Search the folder given as input.
Find all of a certain file type extension.
Print this to another folder.

Is there an easier way of performing this task? Attempting to use os.listdir responds that it can't find the file, as it doesn't accept a variable as input.

```
Directories = [];
InitDirect = str(input('Please insert the file directory you want to search (C:\\x)'))

FileType = str(input('Please state a desired file type (.txt, .png)'))

OutDirect = str(input('Please state the output directory for the files.'))

for file in os.listdir("InitDirect"):
    if file.endswith("FileType"):
        print(os.path.join("InitDirect", file))
```

This is my current code, although likely incorrect. If anyone could help, that'd be great!

Comment: Remove all rhe /" from your last 3 lines. since "" means string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use quotes around the variable names. Adding "" around the variable names actually declares strings and you are not using the value of the variable. Change the code to the following and it should work.

```
Directories = [];
InitDirect = str(input('Please insert the file directory you want to search (C:\\x)'))

FileType = str(input('Please state a desired file type (.txt, .png)'))

OutDirect = str(input('Please state the output directory for the files.'))

for file in os.listdir(InitDirect):
    if file.endswith(FileType):
        print(os.path.join(InitDirect, file))
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped solve the problem I had. Does this have the possibility of printing the files to another folder, or does that require a different set of code?

Comment: When you say print the file are you referring to the contents of the file or just the filenames? If you want to print the content of the file you will need to use open and read. Have a look here -> http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: Thanks! I'll read through that to find the solution. You've been very helpful to me.

Comment: You are most welcome. If my answer helped you can you please accept it by clicking the green check mark?